# How do you throw HttpResponseException in ASP 5 (vnext)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

I'm writing an api controller in ASP 5. I want to return a bad request code exception if the parameters passed to the service are incorrect. In the current version of webapi I would do:

```
throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
```

However `HttpResponseException` is part of `System.Web`, which has been removed from ASP 5 and thus I cannot instantiate it anymore.

What is the proper way to do this in vNext?

Comment: Take a look at http://www.strathweb.com/2015/01/migrating-asp-net-web-api-mvc-6-exploring-web-api-compatibility-shim/.

Answer (score 8):

To answer your question, you can use the [WebApiCompatibilityShim](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/tree/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.WebApiCompatShim) which ports `HttpResponseException` (and many other features) forward into MVC 6. (thanks to DWright for the link to [that article](http://www.strathweb.com/2015/01/migrating-asp-net-web-api-mvc-6-exploring-web-api-compatibility-shim/).)

It seems like the MVC-6 way to do it is to return an IActionResponse from your method and then call `HttpBadRequest()` which is a method on the base `Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Controller` class that returns an `BadRequestResult`, which I believe is the best way to get a 400 status into the response.

The `Controller` class has methods for other response codes as well - including the `HttpNotFound()` method which causes a 404 to be returned.

See also: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api

Comment: This is accurate. FWIW, the OP seems to be looking for a 400 and not a 404, thus `return HttpBadRequest()`. And came here looking for a 401, or `return HttpUnauthorized()`.

Comment: Thanks, @lc. - I didn't notice the discrepancy. I edited my response.

Comment: The link for the WebApiCompatibilitySim is dead.  Also, could you comment on how we're supposed to respond to basic RESTful requests with MVC5 (which, even in the generated template, are 'void' methods).